# Reboot error: Failed to talk to init daemon

Tags: reboot, init

I am new to Linux. I am trying to reboot my Ubuntu 18.04.6. However, I'm getting this message:

```
$ sudo reboot
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Would anyone be able to suggest what the problem is?

Comment: Is this "real" Ubuntu - or Ubuntu on WSL?

Comment: Hi: Ubuntu on WSL

Comment: In that case, what you're seeing is expected I think

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't restart/shutdown Ubuntu under WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131122/cant-restart-shutdown-ubuntu-under-wsl)

Comment: I installed the command `wsl` and then ran `wsl --shutdown`. I got: 'Unknown command: --shutdown'

Comment: It sounds like you installed the wsl package inside your Ubuntu instance - that's something completely different (the Wsman Shell commandLine). You should issue `wsl --shutdown` in a cmd.exe or PowerShell window of the parent Windows system, not from inside of Ubuntu